# How to export table in text document (ODT or DOCX) to EMF format via api

Tags: api, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I have a text document (ODT or DOCX) with some tables. I use LibreOffice API (in Java) to open this document.

I want to export tables as EMF files. Any ideas?
P.S. Official documentation for LibreOffice (OpenOffice) API is very poor. In this very interesting article http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jlop/ this information is not found.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready-to-use LibreOffice API that can do this, but depending on how you decide on the details, I think this is still doable. Couple of tips:

1. If you want to export tables, first you need to iterate over the table container of the document, `XTextTablesSupplier` allows you to do this.
2. Then you probably want to copy out each and every table to a separate Writer document, so when you export a Writer page, only the table shows up there, nothing else. (Keep in mind that tables may span over multiple pages). Copying content between documents is possible using the `XTextCopy` interface.
3. Once you have a Writer document that contains just a single table, you need to iterate over all pages of the document: the opened document's component can be casted to an `XRenderable`, then `getRendererCount()` tells you about the number of pages. (You could use `XPageCursor` as well, but the former interface will be needed anyway below.)
4. Finally once you have a single page of a single document, you can use the `XRenderer` interface's `render()` method to actually render a page to a vector format.

I would suggest that you consider if you really want to do all this within LibreOffice itself; you could simplify your job if you replace steps 3. and 4. with exporting to PDF, then handle the PDF to EMF conversion yourself.